# How to make a reminder window on mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to make an clock app on mac, when the time is pressing, I want to show a reminder windows on the screen, how can I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting with a simple message box?

```
NSString *caption = @"Reminder";
NSString *text = @"Alarm!";
NSAlert* x = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[x setInformativeText: text];
[x setMessageText: caption];
[x addButtonWithTitle: @"OK"];
[x runModal];
[x release];
```

Comment: You can use `NSRunAlertPanel`